# How do I get rid of unwanted gaps in a horizontal navigation bar?

Tags: html

That was my question, in the form of a question.

Fortunately, I've already whipped up some code and can only point you to errors in the html.. although I don't know what they are. Here's what I've got:

http://cssdesk.com/uDaLg

When the extra navigation links (which would normally be characterized by line breaks) are laid out in my navigation bar, my html puts a gap in the padding on the right side. I have highlighted the background in case you're overly skeptical that it is in fact my css. Of course, you can also go and view the css for yourself.

Comment: I should also be swift to point out that different browsers render faulty html differently, so if you don't see the problem then just, uh, try IE or something. ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: Notes taken, @John. Maybe I'll see you guys around. Helpful bunch, you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a gap between inline elements like spans. There are a couple of ways to get rid of the space. You can put all the spans on one line or you can do something like this to hack it:

```
   <span><a href="#">Link</a></span><!-- 
--><span><a href="#">Link</a></span><!-- 
--><span><a href="#">Link</a></span>
```

Comment: Oh, you are slick! I'm trying to make my site look smooth even if it doesn't render images, but the alt box seems to float upwards. I've tried vertical-align: baseline; but it doesn't seem to work for this kind of thing.